# <Shell> PARAM illegal

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I'm a new bee to shell and would ask for your kindly help.
I created a small script to remove the extra " which is extra when copying Windows file into Linux.
But my script has below issue:
1st error is PARAM is not recognized. (I copied from others)
PARAM=-linux -brnce -cdw: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.

2nd. When I try to ignore PARAM, there is new error
if: Expression Syntax.

The script is as below:

'''

```
#file name: removeQuote.sh
#!/bin/bash
PARAM="-linux -brnce -cdw"
indent $PARAM "$@"


if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        exit 1
fi

if [ $# -ge 3 ] #check if there is output file 
then
        file_path = $3
else
        file_path = $1
fi

vim -e -s -c "%s/\"//g" -c "wq" $file_path
echo "ok, all extra \" removed"
```

'''

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Post your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)